# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\log n)^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus

> How do you find this limit? $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\log n)^{1/n}$$

I came across this elementary problem in Serge Lang's "A First Course in Calculus" but got a bit stuck.  The answer is obviously "1" but how can this be justified?

The intuitive answer is that $\log(n)$ will "slow down" as $n$ gets large, and but taking $n$-th roots many times, it eventually becomes unity.  But how can this be expressed mathematically?

Comment: Hint: $(\log n)^{1/n}=\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\log(n)\right)$.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't $exp(1/n log(n))$ just log(n^1/n)? Shouldn't (log n) be exp(1/n log(log(n))) instead?  What if we need to find the limit of the n-th root of log(n)?

Comment: You are absolutely right, it was a typo. Anyway, $n$ dominates $\log(\log(n))$ as $n\to+\infty$, so you should be able to conclude from there.

Comment: Do you already know $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{1/n}=1$?

Comment: Otherwise you can also show $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}  (\log(n))^{1/n} \leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left( (1+\varepsilon)^n\right)^{1/n} =1+\varepsilon.$$ This works for any $\varepsilon>0$ and thus $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}  (\log(n))^{1/n} \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the squeeze theorem,  using that $1\le\ln n\le n $ and the known limit $n^{1/n}\longrightarrow 1$, we get $1^{1/n}\le(\ln n)^{1/n}\le n^{1/n} $.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\log n)^{1/n}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\log\left((\log n)^{1/n}\right)}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{1}{n}{\log\left(\log n\right)}}$$
$$=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}{\log\left(\log n\right)}}$$

So, the exponent of $e$ is $${\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(\log n\right)}{n}}$$
This is of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, and thus, we can apply L'Hospitals Rule.
$${\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(\log n\right)}{n}}={\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\log n}\frac{1}{n}}{1}}=0$$

Thus,$$=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}{\log\left(\log n\right)}}=e^0=1$$

Comment: Perhaps simpler is to use the squeeze theorem for limits: For all sufficiently large $n$ we have $1^{1/n} \leq (\log n)^{1/n} \leq  n^{1/n},$ and each of $1^{1/n}$ and $n^{1/n}$ approaches $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty,$ so $(\log n)^{1/n}$ approaches $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: Thank you all for your very useful comments! They are most helpful!

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yeah makes sense, this the most basic way I could think of in that moment of time though xd

Comment: @DanielSin no problem, request you to accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Of course, it's only simpler if one already knows $n \rightarrow \infty$ implies $n^{1/n} \rightarrow 1.$ This occurred to me moments after I posted my comment, but I was going out the door at the time and figured I'd acknowledge this if anyone brought it up. Also, I thought this was what you were thinking of when you wrote your other comment about whether the OP knew $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{1/n}=1,$ a comment that was made before I made my comment, so I thought maybe you just wanted to do it "from scratch" without assuming that simpler limit.